# How To Find Root Cause for GWT Permutations

Tags: gwt

I have rather large GWT project that depends on a number of third party libraries.  When compiling the GWT part of the application, I see that the GWT compiler goes through 10 permutations.  But I'm only compiling for 5 different browsers, and for one locale.  How can I figure out what is causing the each permutation?  Is there some setting I can enable that prints out what each permutation is for when it is compiled.  Something that would give me output like:

```
Compiling Permutation 0 - Browser ie8 and Locale En  ....
Compiling Permutation 1 - Browser ie9 and Locale En  ....
```

My gwt.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.0//EN"
   "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='LibraryPlace'>

   <inherits name="com.github.gwtbootstrap.BootstrapNoResources"/>
   <inherits name='com.biglibrary.libraryplace.model.LibraryModel'/>
   <inherits name="com.biglibrary.common.LiCommon"/>
   <inherits name="org.atmosphere.gwt20.AtmosphereGwt20"/>
   <inherits name='com.google.web.bindery.event.EventBinder'/>
   <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>

   <stylesheet src="/css/datepicker.css"/>

   <!-- LATO font -->
   <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic">-->
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <stylesheet src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic"/>
   <!--<stylesheet src="/css/bootstrap.css"/>
   <stylesheet src="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>-->

   <stylesheet src="/css/toastr.css"/>
   <stylesheet src="/css/fullcalendar.css"/>
   <!-- Library Place New Custom CSS based on MyAdmin Theme Custom CSS -->
   <stylesheet src="/css/style.css"/>

   <stylesheet src="/css/clock/clock-style.css"/>


   <source path='resources'/>
   <replace-with class="com.biglibrary.libraryplace.resources.LibraryConfigurator">
      <when-type-is class="com.github.gwtbootstrap.client.ui.config.Configurator"/>
   </replace-with>
   <public path="resources">
      <exclude name="** /*.java"/>
      <exclude name="** /*.class"/>
   </public>


   <!-- Other module inherits-->
   <inherits name="de.devbliss.gwt.xdm.XDM"/>
   <inherits name="com.watopi.chosen.Chosen"/>

   <!-- enable @CORS annotations in restygwt -->
   <extend-configuration-property
      name="org.fusesource.restygwt.annotationresolver"
      value="org.fusesource.restygwt.rebind.CORSAnnotationResolver"/>

   <replace-with class="de.devbliss.gwt.xdm.client.impl.CORSTransportLayer">
      <when-type-is class="com.biglibrary.libraryplace.client.xdr.XDRTransportLayer"/>
      <any>
         <when-property-is name="user.agent"
                           value="gecko1_8"/>
         <when-property-is name="user.agent"
                           value="safari"/>
      </any>
   </replace-with>

   <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>

   <!-- gwt logging properties -->
   <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel"
                 value="FINE"/>

   <set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler"
                 value="ENABLED">
      <any>
         <when-property-is name="user.agent"
                           value="ie8"/>
         <when-property-is name="user.agent"
                           value="ie9"/>
      </any>
   </set-property>

   <!--Gives java like stack trace for errors that come up in js-->
   <set-property name="compiler.emulatedStack"
                 value="true"/>
   <set-configuration-property
      name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames"
      value="true"/>


   <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
   <entry-point class='com.biglibrary.libraryplace.client.LibraryPlace'/>

   <!--Chrome or Safari-->

   <set-property name="user.agent" value="opera,ie8, gecko1_8, safari, ie9"/>

   <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
   <source path='client'/>

   <define-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector"
                                  is-multi-valued="false"/>
   <set-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector"
                               value="com.biglibrary.libraryplace.client.gin.AppGinjector"/>
   <!--
   Ensure Ui Binder files are using Safe HTML to prevent XSS.
   -->
   <set-configuration-property name="UiBinder.useSafeHtmlTemplates"
                               value="true"/>
   <!-- English language, independent of country. -->
   <extend-property name="locale"
                    values="en"/>

   <!-- Default language (English) -->
   <set-property-fallback name="locale"
                          value="en"/>

   <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
   <set-configuration-property name="gwt.superdevmode"
                               value="on"/>
   <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled"
                               value="true"/>
   <set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps"
                 value="true"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thomas Broyer's comment led me to discover that GWT can make a compile report:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html

It gave me a nice print out of why each permutation was being created.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As you are compiling your project using the `xsiframe` linker you will have a `compilation-mappings.txt` file in your javascript folder.

It contains a very useful list with all permutations and the properties which triggers each one.

```
 F7437BC8947642CC76A8E491E7E52DB4.cache.js
 mgwt.os desktop
 user.agent safari 

 F7437BC8947642CC76A8E491E7E52DB4.cache.js
 mgwt.os desktop
 user.agent gecko1_8
 [...]
```

Once you know which properties produce each permutation, you can dive into `*.gwt.xml` files to know which properties are increasing the permutation number.

In your case, if you are using just `en` language, it is better not set it at all, so as gwt will compile only `default`, otherwise it is compiling `default` and `en` languages.

Another useful option for reducing permutations is to use the `collapse-property` feature.

```
 <collapse-property name="language" values="*" />
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it's compiling 5xfor english and 5xfor the default locale (which happens to be English as well).

Comment: I thought that too, so I tried removing the default locale.  But I still ended up with 10 permutations.  Could one of the classes I'm inheriting be adding another locale?

Comment: How did you try removing the default locale? Anyway, there should be a text file with the mappings in the -extra dir IIRC.